# How to use Flex Vertical Center and Viewport Units vh?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple page layout with a vertical centered content box using flex.

I use `min-height: 70vh;` to stretch the container height to allow the content-box to vertical center.

I also have a footer which height gap is stretched to the bottom of the page using `flex: 1;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvod41L2/

[image: layout 1]

**Problem**

If the content-box has enough content that makes it taller than the page the footer is not pushed to the bottom and scrolls with the page. Example: `height: 2000px;`

[image: layout 2]

If I remove `min-height: 70vh;` the footer is pushed to the bottom of the page as it should look.

[image: layout 3]

**HTML/CSS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
            <style>
            html, body {
                  height: 100%;
                  margin: 0;
                  padding: 0;
            }
            body {
                  display: flex;
                  flex-direction: column;
            }
            .header {
                  min-height: 40px;
                  padding: 0.8em 2em;
                  background: black;
                  color: white;
            }
            .flex-container {
                  display: flex;
                  align-items: center;
                  min-height: 70vh;
                  padding: 2em;
                  background: gray;
            }
            .content-box {
                  width: 300px;
                  height: 300px;
                  margin: auto;
                  padding: 2em;
                  text-align: center;
                  background: black;
                  color: white;
            }
            .footer {
                  z-index: 100;
                  position: relative;
                  flex: 1;
                  padding: 2em;
                  background: black;
                  color: white;
            }     
            </style>
      </head>

      <body>
            <div class="header">
                  Header
            </div>

            <div class="flex-container">
                  <div class="content-box">
                        Content Box
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class="footer">
                  Footer
            </div>

      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**SOLUTION - JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/kirandash/2aszagw5/)

Add `flex: 0 0 auto;` to the container

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 70vh;
  padding: 2em;
  background: gray;
  flex: 0 0 auto; /* Added rule */
}
```

I hope that solves the issue.